# Update database table after array query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I found some similar questions but i couldnt figure out how to apply this to my specific case. I have a site where users can rate there favorite post from 1-8. Every number is a different category. 
A table looks like that

```
 value | post_id               
---------------
  3    |   12
  1    |   6
  4    |   13
  2    |   5
  6    |   12
  5    |   6
```

now i need to find out, how often is a post(post_id) ratet in the table, and which is the most frequent category every post is voted in.

for this i use this query

```
$test = $wpdb->get_results('select
    posts_id,
    value,
    count(*)
From
    rating_item_entry_value
group by
    posts_id,
    value
order by
    count(*) desc'); 
echo '<pre>';
print_r($test);
echo '</pre>';
```

and i get this output, where count shows how often a post has been rated and the value is the category for example value 8 == sport

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [posts_id] => 336
            [value] => 8
            [count(*)] => 2
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [posts_id] => 329
            [value] => 2
            [count(*)] => 1
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [posts_id] => 327
            [value] => 3
            [count(*)] => 1
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [posts_id] => 338
            [value] => 1
            [count(*)] => 1
        )

)
```

My problem is now to get the most rated value of every post_id. (e.g. post 1 is most voted for category sport) and update this for every post in another table which has the columns  post id and category.

How would i extend this query to update every post in the category table?
i wanna run this in a cronjob and it must affect every post_id.
I dont know how to fetch the array data and update them for any post. How would a query have to look like? thanks for any help  regards